# Local diffeomorphism between two compact connected manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be two compact and connected manifolds, and 
$$f:M\longrightarrow N$$
a surjective local diffeomorphism. I am trying to show that for each $b\in N$ there exists a connected neighborhood $V$ such that

i) $\quad f^{-1}(V)=U_1\cup\ldots\cup U_r,\quad$ where the $U_j$ are disjoint open sets.

ii) $\quad f\mid_{U_j}\quad $is a diffeomorphism over $V$.

My approach:

For each $a\in f^{-1}(b)$ there are two neighborhoods $U_a$ and $V_a$ (of $a$ and $b$ respectively) such that
$$f\mid_{U_a}:U_a\longrightarrow V_a$$
is a diffeomorphism.

On the other hand, since $f$ is continuous and $M$ is compact, $f^{-1}(b)$ is compact, and is cover by the previously defined $U_a$, there for there are $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in f^{-1}(b)$ such that
$$f^{-1}(b)\subset U_{a_1}\cup\ldots U_{a_n}$$
in fact it must be
$$f^{-1}(b)=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$$
since $f^{-1}(b)\cap U_a=\{a\}$, otherwise it wouldn't be 1-1.

Here comes where I got stuck, my idea now is to make
$$V=V_{a_1}\cap \ldots V_{a_n}$$
and
$$U_j=(f\mid_{U_{a_j}})^{-1}(V), \quad\forall 1\leq j\leq n$$
my problem comes when I try to show i) from here, I don't see why can't there be a point in $f^{-1}(V)$ that is not in any of the $U_j$. Am I missing something and that point really can't exist or do I have to refine the definition of the $U_j$ (and maybe $V$)?

Comment: This argument is the standard non-proof. You absolutely need to use compactness of $M$ (or else you could have (a non-compact) part of $M$ that maps asymptotically closer and closer to $b$ and hence shows up in the preimage. I invite you to draw a picture of such a thing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to shrink $V$ even more because at some point that $x$ will not exist due to $M$ been compact (if it does exist you get a sequence that converges to a point $x_0$ and by continuity $f(x_0)=b$ so it must be in one of the $U_j$), is that it?

Comment: You can complete your argument by showing that $n$ [the number of preimages of $b$] does not depend on $b$.  This is where connectedness comes into play.

Comment: You can also shrink $V$ even more, by removing $f\left(M-\cup U_a\right)$